# Moving from a Process Builder to Flow, can't get similar logic to work in the Flow (trying to trigger on prior owner / owner change)

Tags: visual-workflow, case, record-owner, recordtriggeredflow

We have an old Process Builder that is triggered when a Case is Saved, Created or Edited, and we are recreating that as a Flow.

The Process Builder still runs without errors.

In one of the nodes of the Process Builder, we have logic that is checking on the owner of the case, which seems pretty simple / straightforward.  We want to know when the OwnerID is changed from anything but a User as an owner to a User being the new owner (or as it typical in this flow, the owner changes from a Queue to a Person).

When the flow is run in debug, you can see that it thinks that the prior owner and current owner are the same, but they are not:
[image: prior and current look the same]
[image: what's in the case]

I thought that maybe because I can't change the owner as part of debugging in the flow, that might be the problem, but when this flow runs for real, it skips this path even though I am changing the case owner from a Queue to a user.

Thoughts?  Is this a bug with $record_prior?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try activating the flow and using a send email action for debugging.  You can place them at key points in the flow, and send emails to see what the variable values are at each step.

Comment: The problem ended up being an issue that existed in an earlier part of the flow.